# How can I use select_related in case like this?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have this models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...


class Names(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    ....


class Address(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    ....

class Occupation(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    ....
```

I want to fetch data by join all tables but i keep get error.. any help please?

Comment: fetching data to join all tables is quite vague. Be more specific about what you want and post what you tried

Comment: Also add the full error stacktrace, because there is a lot of info to solve the error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get person and its related models by using serializer you can do like this

```py
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    names = serializer.RelatedField(many=True, queryset=Names.objects.all())
    address = serializer.RelatedField(many=True, queryset=Address.objects.all())
    occupation = serializer.RelatedField(many=True, queryset=Occupation.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__' # or you can add by manually as ('id','person','names','address','occupation')
```